# How do I unclose a topic closed by someone else

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close, re-open, re-close, re-re-open, re-re-close, etc…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25312/close-re-open-re-close-re-re-open-re-re-close-etc)

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260221/whats-with-rubys-percent-syntax-closed) about Ruby's percent syntax and received lots of useful and good examples of where to use it. Someone closed it, however, and I don't think they really read the question, as it certainly was not subjective or argumentative. The title and example may be misleading, but the final paragraph asks the real question: "why and when do I use this?"

I don't think this question should have been closed, and I think many people agree (given the upvotes and stars). How do I revert this?

Comment: Please see this and choose your favorite duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed

Comment: Also, unclose = open

Comment: I choose this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25312

Comment: I edited your question making it **much more** objective and less argumentative, and voted to reopen. See what I changed and try to ask questions the way I did in the future!

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry i guess my moment of frustration got the better of me when writing that post.  Also, thx for the tip Downvoter, 'unclose = open' haha i sometimes wonder what's going on inside my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to i unclose a topic closed by someone else

It's called voting to re-open, and you need to have 3,000 reputation to be able to vote to close or re-open questions.  Asking here on Meta is one good way to alert those that can open it to review whether it should have been closed, and fix it if needed.

> it certainly was not subjective or argumentative.

Actually it was quite subjective and argumentative:

> ...people's obsession...

- You discount that people might be using it for valid reasons, and imply that people who use it are doing so out of blind passion rather than for technical reasons.

> ...How is this possibly more succinct and obvious...

- This isn't bad, but the phrasing used suggests "even a dolt can see I'm correct" rather than *really* asking the question.  This is a rhetorical question, and rhetoric is often subjective and argumentative.

> ...insignificant cool factor...

- Again, you demean those that use this feature as, perhaps, fan-boys who are little more than cool hair and ego.

> The title and example may be misleading but the final paragraph asks the real question of "why and when do I use this?"

Unfortunately by the time you get to the point, you've already hit the hot button for a lot of programmers.  By setting them up in a defensive position you are not really asking for an answer, you are asking for validation of your point of view.

While a good programmer will let all this incendiary opinion slide off their back and answer the question (as several did) you can't count on that, and so should avoid such phrasing when asking a technical question.

Comment: fair enough. thx for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If you get 3000 rep then you can vote to **reopen** any question, you'll see the link under the tags.

If you have 250 rep then you can vote to **reopen** your own questions.

Comment: He can vote to re-open on his own questions regardless of rep

Comment: @Downvoter: actually, no. You need 250 rep to do that.

Comment: @Koper, thanks, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @Koper, really? You learn something new everyday...

Comment: 3000 rep is a lot nowadays, where all the easy question were made and answered =(